# Uploading image string to Google Drive using pydrive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive, bytesio

I need to upload an image string (as the one you get from `requests.get(url).content`) to google drive using the PyDrive package. I checked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58579158/upload-image-to-google-drive-using-pydrive) but the answer accepted there was to save it in a temporary file on a local drive and then upload that. 
However, I cannot do that because of local storage and permission restrictions. 
The accepted answer was previously to use `SetContentString(image_string.decode('utf-8'))` since

> `SetContentString` requires a parameter of type `str` not `bytes`.

However the error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte` came up, as in the comments on that answer.
Is there any way to do this without using a temporary file, using `PIL`/`BytesIO`/anything that can convert it to be uploaded correctly as a string or somehow using PIL manipulated as an image and uploaded using `SetContentFile()`?

A basic example of what I'm trying to do is:

```
img_content = requests.get('https://i.imgur.com/A5gIh7W.jpeg')
file = drive.CreateFile({...})
file.setContentString(img_content.decode('utf-8'))
file.Upload()
```

Comment: Thank you for asking this question! Even after searching for hours, I couldn't find a similar issue anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw the document ([Upload and update file content](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html?highlight=upload#upload-and-update-file-content)) of pydrive, it says as follows.

> Managing file content is as easy as managing file metadata. You can set file content with either SetContentFile(filename) or SetContentString(content) and call Upload() just as you did to upload or update file metadata.

And, I searched about the method for directly uploading the binary data to Google Drive. But, I couldn't find it. From this situation, I thought that there might not be such method. So, in this answer, I would like to propose to upload the binary data using `requests` module. In this case, the access token is retrieved from the authorization script of pydrive. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
import io
import json
import requests


url = 'https://i.imgur.com/A5gIh7W.jpeg' # Please set the direct link of the image file.
filename = 'sample file' # Please set the filename on Google Drive.
folder_id = 'root' # Please set the folder ID. The file is put to this folder.

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
metadata = {
    "name": filename,
    "parents": [folder_id]
}
files = {
    'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(metadata), 'application/json'),
    'file': io.BytesIO(requests.get(url).content)
}
r = requests.post(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",
    headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + gauth.credentials.access_token},
    files=files
)
print(r.text)
```

#### Note:

- In this script, it supposes that your URL is the direct link of the image file. Please be careful this.
- In this case, `uploadType=multipart` is used. The official document says as follows. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)

  > Use this upload type to quickly transfer a small file (5 MB or less) and metadata that describes the file, in a single request. To perform a multipart upload, refer to Perform a multipart upload.

  - When you want to upload the data of the large size, please use the resumable upload. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable)

#### References:

- [Upload and update file content of pydrive](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html?highlight=upload#upload-and-update-file-content)
- [Upload file data of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)

Comment: Thank you, this works flawlessly. Shame that PyDrive can't handle such a simple task though.

Comment: @Samarth Bhatia Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: @Tanaike Great answer! I was wondering if we could specify the image dimensions while uploading on google drive