# How to upload files on GDrive from URL without saving it locally

Tags: python, file-upload, python-requests, google-drive-api, bytesio

I am trying to upload an image from URL to Google Drive Folder using GDrive API in Python.

I am trying to directly fetch the image data and upload it to drive without saving it locally. Through my research I came to know about BytesIO but it is giving the following error

main.py

```
import requests
import os
import io
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
load_dotenv()
from io import BytesIO

import tempfile
# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client
gauth = GoogleAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# Set the ID of the folder you want to upload the file to
folder_id = "1GUUQO5huBXFQfsx_on7DdDDmkHnrZIsd"

# Set the URL of the image you want to fetch
url = "image URL"

# Set the authorization header using the API key stored in environment variables
headers = {"Authorization": os.getenv("API")}

# Fetch the image data from the URL
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Check if the response status code is OK (200)
#if response.status_code == 200:
    # Create a BytesIO object and write the image data to it
    #  with io.BytesIO(response.content) as fp:
    #     fp.seek(0)
    #     file = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'hello2.jpg', 'parents': [{'id': folder_id}]})
    #     file.SetContentFile(fp)
    #     file.Upload()
    headers = {'Authorization': os.getenv("API")}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

headers = {'Authorization': os.getenv("API")}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
# Create a BytesIO object and write the image data to it
    with BytesIO(response.content) as fp:
    # Set the file name for the image
        filename = 'hello2.jpg'
        
        # Create a new file in Google Drive and upload the image data
        file = drive.CreateFile({'title': filename, 'parents': [{'id': folder_id}]})
        file.SetContentFile(fp)
        file.Upload()
        print(f'Image {filename} uploaded to Google Drive successfully.')
else:
    print("Error fetching image data", response.status_code)
```

Error/ Output:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not BytesIO
```

I tried fp.getValue(), fp.read() but wasn't able to solve the error

Any help or advice is appreciated, Thank you

Comment: I thought that this thread might be an answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67499647

Comment: It worked!, Thank you for your help! Appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `It worked!, Thank you for your help! Appreciate it.`, I flagged it as a duplicate question.